# Как задать значение, используемое в целевом элементе, если значение источника равно null

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте! Меня интересует такой вопрос: у меня асинхронно скачивается коллекция картинок и привязывается к странице wpf, но во время скачивания, когда значение каждого элемента картинок равняется null, у меня выходит пустое пространство. Как закачать картинку по умолчанию в это пустое место? Я пробовал параметр TargetNullValue но результата никакого нету.

Обрывок кода WPF:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentMedias}" >
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="6" />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Image Source="{Binding Path=Images, IsAsync=True, TargetNullValue=DefaultImage}"/>
           </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Обрывок C#:

```
private ImageSource defaultImage = null;
public ImageSource DefaultImage
{
   get { return defaultImage; }
   set
   {
      defaultImage = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultImage");
   }
 }
```

```
public class SelectedMedia : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private ImageSource images = null;
   public ImageSource Images
   {
      get { return images; }
      set { images = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Images");         }
}
```

```
public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
{
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
           foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasError"));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultImageSource">D:\Loading.png</BitmapImage>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image
                Source="{Binding Image, TargetNullValue={StaticResource DefaultImageSource}}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Вместо `D:\Loading.png` вам нужно, понятно, реальная картинка (наверное, pack URI, если вы добавляете в ресурсы).

---

Если вы картинку по умолчанию действительно хотите положить в VM и привязываться к ней через `Binding`, подойдёт такой код:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:FirstNonNullValueConverter x:Key="FirstNonNullValueConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="50">
                <Image.Source>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FirstNonNullValueConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Image"/>
                        <Binding Path="DefaultImage"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Нужно будет добавить конвертер в code-behind:

```
public class FirstNonNullValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.SkipWhile(v => v == null).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                                CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

(`PriorityBinding` делает почти то, что надо, но именно *почти*.)

Comment: Всё всем большое спасибо за помощь, у меня всё получилось, был ещё вариант написания через тригеры, но у меня всё заработало. Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю изменить DataTemplate так, чтобы загружающаяся картинка закрывала собой placeHolder:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="imgHolder" Source="Assets/placeHolderImage.jpg"  Height="100" Width="100" />
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Images, IsAsync=True, TargetNullValue=DefaultImage}" Height="100" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```